# how we stop sending mail in spam folder (sending over 30000 mails)

Tags: .net, email, spam

I am sending mail in my website using System.Net.Mail namespace but these mail are received in spam folder i don't want to receive them into spam folder. What should i do to stop them to go into spam folder, i want to receive them into inbox.

Note:- Mail is spamming after sending 30000 e-mails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search. There are a _lot_ of questions about this on this site already, just look at the "Related" links on this page.

Comment: You have to make a research first. It depends on the nature of your mail messages. Then check out each mail server that puts your mail into the spam box. All of them have some rules that you must follow, like headers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the spam filter on other client PCs. If this were possible, spam filters would be useless and we'd be buried under a sea of rubbish emails.

To stop it hitting the spam filter, I'd stop sending spam.

On a related note:

[.NET System.Net.Mail messages are always being flagged junk, on internal server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907644/net-system-net-mail-messages-are-always-being-flagged-junk-on-internal-server)